# List of extinct animals

Tags: curated-data, entity

There is a list of endangered species

```
EntityList[EntityClass["Species", "EndangeredSpecies"]]
```

[image]

How to make a list of extinct animals by using *Mathematica*?

Comment: have you looked at `EntityClassList` ?

Comment: If you manage this it'll be a long list. From wikipedia [Extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction) "More than 99 percent of all species, amounting to over five billion species, that ever lived on Earth are estimated to be extinct" :P

Comment: N.J.Evans just gave the best evidence there is for "Creation": a - likely bored - old man is sitting around killing his toys... :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to get your **EndangeredSpecies** Species list because of **A computation timed out. >>** but try with this:

```
el = EntityList[EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]]
```

[image]

```
CanonicalName[el]
```

> `{Albania,Andorra,Austria,Belarus,Belgium,BosniaHerzegovina,Bulgaria,Croatia,Cyprus,CzechRepublic,Denmark,Estonia,FaroeIslands,Finland,France,Germany,Gibraltar,Greece,Guernsey,Hungary,Iceland,Ireland,IsleOfMan,Italy,Jersey,Kosovo,Latvia,Liechtenstein,Lithuania,Luxembourg,Macedonia,Malta,Moldova,Monaco,Montenegro,Netherlands,Norway,Poland,Portugal,Romania,SanMarino,Serbia,Slovakia,Slovenia,Spain,Svalbard,Sweden,Switzerland,Ukraine,UnitedKingdom,VaticanCity}`

Answer (score 1):

Among all outputs of `EntityValue[]`, only `"Species"` seems indeed connected with what you want:

```
TableForm @ Partition[EntityClassList["Species"], 5]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't see anything related to *extinct* species...

By the way, one can obtain a given number of randomly chosen endangered species via

```
RandomEntity[EntityClass["Species", "EndangeredSpecies"], 5]
```

[image]