# Knowledge Domains

Tags: curated-data, entity

What function will return a list of all the domains in the knowledge representation? The Mathematica reference lists CountryData, CityData, ChemicalData, FinancialData, WeatherData, WordData, PersonData as examples, but they are clearly examples.

I used wolfram-alpha-queries as a tag, but given the integration of the Knowledge Representation System more deeply into the Wolfram Language that tag isn't right. We need a knowledge-representation-system tag.

Comment: [Related?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128077/list-of-extinct-animals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) to obtain a list of all known entities in *Mathematica*.

```
EntityValue[]
```

The above returns 241 entities.  Not all of these entities have functions defined.  However, you can query them and their properties using the functions found on the [Knowledge Representation & Access](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/KnowledgeRepresentationAndAccess.html) guide in the documentation.

I recomend starting with [`EntityClassList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityClassList.html) and [`EntityProperties`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperties.html). [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) is used to return properties of entities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that I was implicitly asking if Entities and domains are equivalent. This page bit.ly/2dRUyz0 in the reference doesn't make it clear. If a domain is an entity, then you answered both my explicit and implicit question.